How do I get keras to format its output correctly?
When I run model.fit in keras, I get output like this (repeated once per epoch):

Epoch 63/50000
←[1m1/1←[0m ←[32m????????????????????←[0m←[37m←[0m←[1m0s←[0m 14ms/step - loss: 0.1632

I am using Python 3.12.3 under Windows 11. I have tried the Windows cmd console and a Far Manager console, with identical results.
I'm not trying to suppress this output, I just want to know what it's trying to tell me.
Here is the complete source code (based on sample code from Dominik Klein's excellent introductory book Neural Networks for Chess):
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import random

random.seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

x = []
y = []

x = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
y = [0,1,1,0]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential ()
model.add (tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,)))
model.add (tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add (tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

model.fit (np.array(x), np.array(y), batch_size=4, epochs=50000)

